# How to preload css called in JS

Tags: javascript

How do I preload the css in the following code? I have updated my code with Denis suggestions, but it did not work. Now the pages are not finding css at all. I might be missing something since I do not have much about js. Am i missing something? Thanks again Denis, for your suggestion.

This is a free template that i downloaded somewhere. Its quite lite and solves my pbn needs while keeping the site blazing fast. But I have never seen a html template calling css from a js before. I know how to preload files in html, but no clue what would be the proper attribute for it to be used in a js. This can get me the 100 page score i have been trying for long. Any of JS masters help will be much appreciated.

```js
(function($) {

 const item = {
    reset: 'full',
    breakpoints: {
        global:     { range: '*', rel: 'preload', href: 'css/style.css', containers: 1400, grid: { gutters: 50 } },
        wide:       { range: '-1680', rel: 'preload', href: 'css/style-wide.css', containers: 1200, grid: { gutters: 40 } },
        normal:     { range: '-1280', rel: 'preload', href: 'css/style-normal.css', containers: 960, lockViewport: true },
        narrow:     { range: '-980', rel: 'preload', href: 'css/style-narrow.css', containers: '95%', grid: { gutters: 30 } },
        narrower:   { range: '-840', rel: 'preload', href: 'css/style-narrower.css', grid: { gutters: 20, collapse: 1 } },
        mobile:     { range: '-640', rel: 'preload', href: 'css/style-mobile.css', grid: { gutters: 15, collapse: 2 } }
    }
}


Object.keys(item.breakpoints).forEach(key=>{
  var res = document.createElement("link"); 
  res.rel = item.breakpoints[key].rel; 
  res.as = "style";
  res.href = item.breakpoints[key].href;
  document.head.appendChild(res)
})
}
 }, {
  layers: {
   layers: {
    navPanel: {
     animation: 'pushX',
     breakpoints: 'narrower',
     clickToClose: true,
     height: '100%',
     hidden: true,
     html: '<div data-action="navList" data-args="nav"></div>',
     orientation: 'vertical',
     position: 'top-left',
     side: 'left',
     width: 275
    },
    titleBar: {
     breakpoints: 'narrower',
     height: 44,
     html: '<span class="toggle" data-action="toggleLayer" data-args="navPanel"></span><span class="title" data-action="copyHTML" data-args="logo"></span>',
     position: 'top-left',
     side: 'top',
     width: '100%'
    }
   }
  }
 });

 $(function() {

  var $window = $(window);
   
  // Forms (IE<10).
   var $form = $('form');
   if ($form.length > 0) {
    
    $form.find('.form-button-submit')
     .on('click', function() {
      $(this).parents('form').submit();
      return false;
     });
  
    if (skel.vars.IEVersion < 10) {
     $.fn.n33_formerize=function(){var _fakes=new Array(),_form = $(this);_form.find('input[type=text],textarea').each(function() { var e = $(this); if (e.val() == '' || e.val() == e.attr('placeholder')) { e.addClass('formerize-placeholder'); e.val(e.attr('placeholder')); } }).blur(function() { var e = $(this); if (e.attr('name').match(/_fakeformerizefield$/)) return; if (e.val() == '') { e.addClass('formerize-placeholder'); e.val(e.attr('placeholder')); } }).focus(function() { var e = $(this); if (e.attr('name').match(/_fakeformerizefield$/)) return; if (e.val() == e.attr('placeholder')) { e.removeClass('formerize-placeholder'); e.val(''); } }); _form.find('input[type=password]').each(function() { var e = $(this); var x = $($('<div>').append(e.clone()).remove().html().replace(/type="password"/i, 'type="text"').replace(/type=password/i, 'type=text')); if (e.attr('id') != '') x.attr('id', e.attr('id') + '_fakeformerizefield'); if (e.attr('name') != '') x.attr('name', e.attr('name') + '_fakeformerizefield'); x.addClass('formerize-placeholder').val(x.attr('placeholder')).insertAfter(e); if (e.val() == '') e.hide(); else x.hide(); e.blur(function(event) { event.preventDefault(); var e = $(this); var x = e.parent().find('input[name=' + e.attr('name') + '_fakeformerizefield]'); if (e.val() == '') { e.hide(); x.show(); } }); x.focus(function(event) { event.preventDefault(); var x = $(this); var e = x.parent().find('input[name=' + x.attr('name').replace('_fakeformerizefield', '') + ']'); x.hide(); e.show().focus(); }); x.keypress(function(event) { event.preventDefault(); x.val(''); }); });  _form.submit(function() { $(this).find('input[type=text],input[type=password],textarea').each(function(event) { var e = $(this); if (e.attr('name').match(/_fakeformerizefield$/)) e.attr('name', ''); if (e.val() == e.attr('placeholder')) { e.removeClass('formerize-placeholder'); e.val(''); } }); }).bind("reset", function(event) { event.preventDefault(); $(this).find('select').val($('option:first').val()); $(this).find('input,textarea').each(function() { var e = $(this); var x; e.removeClass('formerize-placeholder'); switch (this.type) { case 'submit': case 'reset': break; case 'password': e.val(e.attr('defaultValue')); x = e.parent().find('input[name=' + e.attr('name') + '_fakeformerizefield]'); if (e.val() == '') { e.hide(); x.show(); } else { e.show(); x.hide(); } break; case 'checkbox': case 'radio': e.attr('checked', e.attr('defaultValue')); break; case 'text': case 'textarea': e.val(e.attr('defaultValue')); if (e.val() == '') { e.addClass('formerize-placeholder'); e.val(e.attr('placeholder')); } break; default: e.val(e.attr('defaultValue')); break; } }); window.setTimeout(function() { for (x in _fakes) _fakes[x].trigger('formerize_sync'); }, 10); }); return _form; };
     $form.n33_formerize();
    }

   }

  // Dropdowns.
   $('#nav > ul').dropotron({
    offsetY: -15,
    hoverDelay: 0
   });

 });

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object.keys` for get array of breakpoints item, then you can appendChild to `document.head`

So, write code like this:

```
const item = {
    reset: 'full',
    breakpoints: {
        global:     { range: '*', rel: 'preload', href: 'css/style.css', containers: 1400, grid: { gutters: 50 } },
        wide:       { range: '-1680', rel: 'preload', href: 'css/style-wide.css', containers: 1200, grid: { gutters: 40 } },
        normal:     { range: '-1280', rel: 'preload', href: 'css/style-normal.css', containers: 960, lockViewport: true },
        narrow:     { range: '-980', rel: 'preload', href: 'css/style-narrow.css', containers: '95%', grid: { gutters: 30 } },
        narrower:   { range: '-840', rel: 'preload', href: 'css/style-narrower.css', grid: { gutters: 20, collapse: 1 } },
        mobile:     { range: '-640', rel: 'preload', href: 'css/style-mobile.css', grid: { gutters: 15, collapse: 2 } }
    }
}


Object.keys(item.breakpoints).forEach(key=>{
  var res = document.createElement("link"); 
  res.rel = item.breakpoints[key].rel; 
  res.as = "style";
  res.href = item.breakpoints[key].href;
  document.head.appendChild(res)
})
```

See in playground: https://jsfiddle.net/denisstukalov/3euofv17/#&togetherjs=RqKywyBFh0

Comment: OMG, worked like a charm. My page speed score is 100 now. It was bugging me for a while.

Comment: Weird, It did not work actually, the pages now cant find the css files, hence pages are broken. I have updated my post with the whole code, did i miss anything?  I'm truly grateful that you answered. But solving this would be very satisfying. I posted this to many forums, no one replied. Stackoverflow is love. Thanks to you again.